# Can I have one table be an "alias", or "symlink", to another?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have two tables with the same structure, A and B. A certain application is written so that it always writes the same data to both tables.

After a discussion with a colleague about the potential to save drive space, I'm wondering if mysql or postgresql has the ability to create on table as an "alias", or "symlink", of another.

I want the behaviour to be very similar to that of a soft file symlink; where reading from either the symlink itself or it's target will yield the same output, and writing to either will update the target.

Comment: Have you considered a view of the table?

Comment: In SQL Server you could just use a view.

Comment: Which RDBMS? You've tagged MySQL and Postgres. Views will work in most RDBMSes. Oracle has synonyms, which are the same as Unix symbolic links

Comment: MySQL and Postgres, yes. I mention them specifically in the text as well. I thought Views was somehow not quite what I was looking for, but perhaps it will be just fine. Thanks a lot. Post some answers :)

Comment: and why do you need two tables?

Comment: As @miracle173 asked, if you want the two tables to behave exactly the same and have the same data always, why would you need 2 of them?

Comment: _I_ don't need two tables, but the application in question is designed so it won't function otherwise.  [Background question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32287/how-to-disable-the-revision-feature-completely)

Comment: but if the appplication writes always in both tables that are basically the same table because you use an "alias" or a "symlink" then I would expect that you write each dataset twice in that table.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't think about that. :/ Thanks for pointing it out. I'll see if I can think of a meaningful rewording of the question.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, a new Postgresql lets you have `INSTEAD OF` triggers on views. So having one table, one view as `SELECT * FROM table1`, and `INSTEAD OF` trigger for `insert, update, delete` should work for you. This approach is not gonna work in Mysql though

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in MySQL (using MyISAM storage engine only) to create a table from scratch using symlinks. It is posssible in Linux and Windows (using hardlinks) :

Here are my past posts on this subject

- [Can I specify a different disk for a specific MySQL table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10108/can-i-specify-a-different-disk-for-a-specific-mysql-table/10109#10109)
- [Dynamically changeable database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/dynamically-changeable-database/5965#5965)

However, what you are proposing would have to be done outside of MySQL in Linux.

For this example

- /var/lib/mysql is datadir
- Create table1 as MyISAM table in database mydb
- Create table2 as pure symlinks to table1

STEP 01) Create table1

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.table1
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    mydata varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

STEP 02) Create three symlinks to mimic TableB

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/mydb
ln -s table1.frm table2.frm
ln -s table1.MYD table2.MYD
ln -s table1.MYI table2.MYI
```

STEP 03) Try inserting into table1 and reading from table2. Then try the reverse.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (mydata) VALUES ('rolando'),('edwards');
SELECT * FROM table2;
INSERT INTO table2 (mydata) VALUES ('abraham'),('lincoln');
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

If everything behaves normal, then this is how you can do this.

CAVEAT

1. There is only one table, table1
2. If you do any DDL

   - Perform the DDL on table1
   - You must recreate the table2 symlinks after DDL against table1