# About changing data path by database

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to change physical path by database?

For example :

I have 2 databases in server.

database1 will be located in /data/database1/

database2 will be located in /data/database2/

Is this possible ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only running one mysqld instance and want to physically store databases on different disks, here is an approach:

Let's say you

- datadir is `/data`
- Two databases

  - `database1`
  - `database2`
- you have a Disk Volume mounted on `/data1`
- you have a Disk Volume mounted on `/data2`

## All MYISAM

```
cp /data/database1/* /data1
cp /data/database2/* /data2
chown -R mysql:mysql /data1
chown -R mysql:mysql /data2
mv /data/database1 /data/database1_old
mv /data/database2 /data/database2_old
ln -s /data1 /data/database1
ln -s /data2 /data/database2
chown -R mysql:mysql /data/database1
chown -R mysql:mysql /data/database2
```

After this, when you run `SHOW DATABASES;` make sure the tables in database1 and database2 are fully accessible. If they are, you could then do

```
DROP TABLE database1_old;
DROP TABLE database2_old;
```

## All InnoDB or Mixture of InnoDB/MyISAM

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQL_CONN} --single-transaction --routines -triggers"
mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} database1 > database1.sql
mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} database2 > database2.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"DROP DATABASE database1; DROP DATABASE database2;"
chown -R mysql:mysql /data1
chown -R mysql:mysql /data2
ln -s /data1 /data/database1
ln -s /data2 /data/database2
chown -R mysql:mysql /data/database1
chown -R mysql:mysql /data/database2
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -Ddatabase1 < database1.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -Ddatabase2 < database2.sql
```

## CAVEATS

- Please test this on a staging server
- Please make backups before doing this
- Please test full accessibility (SELECT queries)
- Heads up on InnoDB: This may not produce better performance for `.ibd` files sitting on a disk volume apart from `ibdata1`. I wrote about this before

  - `Feb 06, 2012` : [MySQL tables/databases into different disks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12245/mysql-tables-databases-into-different-disks/12342#12342)
  - `Aug 07, 2011` : [MySQL InnoDB data file directly on a disk slice (fixed-size)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/mysql-innodb-data-file-directly-on-a-disk-slice-fixed-size/4425#4425)

Comment: I disagree that the dump and restore is necessary with `InnoDB`.  Your "All MyISAM" example is completely safe with `InnoDB` as long as you shut down the MySQL server before moving the directories and creating the symlinks and restart it afterwards.  MySQL fully honors directory symlinks and the ibd files will be identical in the old and new locations if copied with the server shut down.  The only thing that can get you into trouble is if you try to symlink at the *file* level instead of the *directory* level.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, in your **my.cnf** you can specify multiple mysqld sections as follow:

```
[mysqld1]
datadir                  = /database/data1/mysql
port                     = 3306
socket                   = /database/tmp/mysql1.sock
pid-file                 = /database/tmp/mysql1.pid
...

[mysqld2]
datadir                  = /database/data2/mysql
port                     = 3307
socket                   = /database/tmp/mysql2.sock
pid-file                 = /database/tmp/mysql2.pid
...
```

Then use the [**mysqld_multi**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-multi.html) program to start and stop the mysqld you want to:

```
mysqld_multi start 2
```

Max.

Comment: This applies only a person is running two instances of mysqld on different ports.

Comment: Sure, i mentioned in my conf example. But thanks for precision.

Comment: Thanks. Is it now possible to do this with 1 instance? I mean i dont want to run 2 mysql same time.

Comment: I added the response in a new "response"

Answer (score 0):

Know that if you want to use the same MySQL instance, you "can't chose" file location. In MySQL we don't have this flexibility because we don't have the "notion" of "Tablespaces" in oracle or "File Groups" in SQL Server.

You just choose a location for all your datafiles in the **my.cnf** file, you can use the parameter **file_per_table** when you want to split your data in different files (one per table) but all these files will in **datadir**.

One solution is to use **symlinks** in UNIX if you want to "load balanced" your disk usages (The solution that Rolando explain)